# CSS selector for element being edited (not hover!), only WebKit

Tags: css, webkit, cursor

I have elements that are editable (content-editable, that is). Each one is inside regular spans. Is there a way to add a border to the span where the text cursor (insertion point) is? I know that for the "mouse" cursor you can use ::hover.

```
<span class=one>alpha</span>
<span class=one>beta</span>
<span class=one>gamma</span>
```

For example, if "|" is the text insertion point, I would like that the word "one" becomes a red border

```
al|pha beta gamma
```

No Javascript, just CSS.

Thank you!

Comment: `:active`? `:focus`?

Comment: Hi stachu. Active works as long as I press the mouse button, then it is gone (WebKit)

Comment: Your welcome brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use selector `:focus`

> Note: the span must be content-editable

**CSS**

```
.one:focus{
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/L1ec56b5/1/)**